# Roll balance foward fill in the gap

Tags: sql, oracle

guys I'm a bit stumped on this one and wonder if you guys can help me. I have a table DDL like such.

```
CREATE TABLE "BISAMPLE"."G_LEDGER" 
   ( "FUND" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
  "ORG" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
  "ACCT" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
  "FY" NUMBER, 
  "FP" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
  "BUDGET" NUMBER(17,2), 
  "YTD" NUMBER(17,2), 
  "ENCB" NUMBER(17,2), 
  "PROG" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)
   )
```

and then within this table, I have some financial data like the below
Table insert:

```
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',6,'03',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',6,'03',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',6,'03',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',6,'04',15000,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',6,'04',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',6,'04',97410,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',6,'05',15000,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',6,'05',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',6,'05',97410,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',6,'06',20000,11019.9,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',6,'06',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',6,'06',119264,7329.97,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',6,'07',20000,11019.9,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',6,'07',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',6,'07',119264,17772.95,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',6,'08',20000,11019.9,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',6,'08',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',6,'08',119264,57304.11,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',6,'09',20000,11019.9,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',6,'09',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',6,'09',127514,69020.23,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',6,'10',20000,11019.9,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',6,'10',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',6,'10',127514,81768.35,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',6,'11',20000,11019.9,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',6,'11',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',6,'11',127514,91685.63,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',6,'12',20000,11019.9,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',6,'12',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',6,'12',127514,97656.09,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'00',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'00',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'00',0,0,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'01',20000,11019.9,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'01',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'01',127514,110820.64,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'02',20000,11019.9,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'02',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'02',127514,117380.28,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'03',40000,11019.9,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'03',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'03',288247,126847.56,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'04',40000,16103.98,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'04',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'04',288247,140405.86,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'05',40000,17209.37,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'05',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'05',288247,158602.13,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'06',40000,17209.37,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'06',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'06',288247,171656.04,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'07',40000,17209.37,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'07',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'07',288247,188242.41,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'08',40000,17209.37,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'08',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'08',288247,214201.42,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'09',40000,17209.37,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'09',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'09',288247,224688.09,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'10',40000,17209.37,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'10',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'10',288247,232076.97,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'11',40000,17209.37,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'11',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'11',288247,242507.33,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','2010',7,'12',40000,17209.37,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','3017',7,'12',0,680,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',7,'12',288247,253002.16,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'00',1054464.33,976361.88,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'01',1047449.31,1002201.54,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'02',1047449.31,997478.18,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'03',1047449.31,997478.18,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'04',1047449.31,998023.18,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'05',1047449.31,998023.18,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'06',1047449.31,998023.18,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'07',1047449.31,998023.18,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'08',1047449.31,998023.18,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'09',1047449.31,998023.18,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'10',1047449.31,985049.76,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'11',1047449.31,985049.76,0,'121');
Insert into G_LEDGER (FUND,ORG,ACCT,FY,FP,BUDGET,YTD,ENCB,PROG) values ('202118','3662','7001',15,'12',1047449.31,985049.76,0,'121');
```

if you run a simple select statement you will get a result set that looks like the below.

```
202118  3662    2010    121 6   3   0   0   0
202118  3662    3017    121 6   3   0   0   0
202118  3662    7001    121 6   3   0   0   0
202118  3662    2010    121 6   4   15000   0   0
202118  3662    3017    121 6   4   0   0   0
202118  3662    7001    121 6   4   97410   0   0
202118  3662    2010    121 6   5   15000   0   0
202118  3662    3017    121 6   5   0   0   0
202118  3662    7001    121 6   5   97410   0   0
202118  3662    2010    121 6   6   20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 6   6   0   0   0
202118  3662    7001    121 6   6   119264  7329.97 0
202118  3662    2010    121 6   7   20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 6   7   0   0   0
202118  3662    7001    121 6   7   119264  17772.95    0
202118  3662    2010    121 6   8   20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 6   8   0   0   0
202118  3662    7001    121 6   8   119264  57304.11    0
202118  3662    2010    121 6   9   20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 6   9   0   0   0
202118  3662    7001    121 6   9   127514  69020.23    0
202118  3662    2010    121 6   10  20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 6   10  0   0   0
202118  3662    7001    121 6   10  127514  81768.35    0
202118  3662    2010    121 6   11  20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 6   11  0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 6   11  127514  91685.63    0
202118  3662    2010    121 6   12  20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 6   12  0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 6   12  127514  97656.09    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   0   0   0   0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   0   0   0   0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   0   0   0   0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   1   20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   1   0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   1   127514  110820.6    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   2   20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   2   0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   2   127514  117380.3    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   3   40000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   3   0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   3   288247  126847.6    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   4   40000   16103.98    0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   4   0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   4   288247  140405.9    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   5   40000   17209.37    0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   5   0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   5   288247  158602.1    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   6   40000   17209.37    0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   6   0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   6   288247  171656  0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   7   40000   17209.37    0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   7   0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   7   288247  188242.4    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   8   40000   17209.37    0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   8   0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   8   288247  214201.4    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   9   40000   17209.37    0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   9   0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   9   288247  224688.1    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   10  40000   17209.37    0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   10  0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   10  288247  232077  0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   11  40000   17209.37    0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   11  0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   11  288247  242507.3    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   12  40000   17209.37    0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   12  0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   12  288247  253002.2    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   13  20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   13  0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   13  127514  117380.3    0
202118  3662    2010    121 7   14  20000   11019.9 0
202118  3662    3017    121 7   14  0   680 0
202118  3662    7001    121 7   14  127514  117380.3    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  0   1054464 976361.9    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  1   1047449 1002202 0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  2   1047449 997478.2    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  3   1047449 997478.2    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  4   1047449 998023.2    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  5   1047449 998023.2    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  6   1047449 998023.2    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  7   1047449 998023.2    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  8   1047449 998023.2    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  9   1047449 998023.2    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  10  1047449 985049.8    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  11  1047449 985049.8    0
202118  3662    7001    121 15  12  1047449 985049.8    0
```

You'll notice that for each ACCT I have an FY and FP but once I get to FY 15 I no longer have the data values from the previous FY for the other two accounts 2010 and 3017. I would like to create a query that basically brings does ending balances for those accounts forward. So for example. The ending balance for account 3017 as of FY 7 and FP12 is 0 for budget and 680 for YTD. Likewise, for the account 2010, the ending balance is 40000 for budget and 17209.37 for YTD. To be more specific if the account does not exist in the current max "FY" (in this case FY 15) than I would like to query the last max "FY" for that fund and show that balance for those accounts that were left behind. Here is the **expected** output.

```
FUND    ORG ACCT    FY  FP  BUDGET  YTD ENCB    PROG
202118  3662    2010    6   3   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    3017    6   3   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    7001    6   3   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    2010    6   4   15000   0   0   121
202118  3662    3017    6   4   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    7001    6   4   97410   0   0   121
202118  3662    2010    6   5   15000   0   0   121
202118  3662    3017    6   5   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    7001    6   5   97410   0   0   121
202118  3662    2010    6   6   20000   11019.9 0   121
202118  3662    3017    6   6   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    7001    6   6   119264  7329.97 0   121
202118  3662    2010    6   7   20000   11019.9 0   121
202118  3662    3017    6   7   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    7001    6   7   119264  17772.95    0   121
202118  3662    2010    6   8   20000   11019.9 0   121
202118  3662    3017    6   8   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    7001    6   8   119264  57304.11    0   121
202118  3662    2010    6   9   20000   11019.9 0   121
202118  3662    3017    6   9   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    7001    6   9   127514  69020.23    0   121
202118  3662    2010    6   10  20000   11019.9 0   121
202118  3662    3017    6   10  0   0   0   121
202118  3662    7001    6   10  127514  81768.35    0   121
202118  3662    2010    6   11  20000   11019.9 0   121
202118  3662    3017    6   11  0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    6   11  127514  91685.63    0   121
202118  3662    2010    6   12  20000   11019.9 0   121
202118  3662    3017    6   12  0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    6   12  127514  97656.09    0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   0   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   0   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   0   0   0   0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   1   20000   11019.9 0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   1   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   1   127514  110820.6    0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   2   20000   11019.9 0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   2   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   2   127514  117380.3    0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   3   40000   11019.9 0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   3   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   3   288247  126847.6    0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   4   40000   16103.98    0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   4   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   4   288247  140405.9    0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   5   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   5   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   5   288247  158602.1    0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   6   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   6   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   6   288247  171656  0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   7   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   7   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   7   288247  188242.4    0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   8   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   8   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   8   288247  214201.4    0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   9   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   9   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   9   288247  224688.1    0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   10  40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   10  0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   10  288247  232077  0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   11  40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   11  0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   11  288247  242507.3    0   121
202118  3662    2010    7   12  40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    3017    7   12  0   680 0   121
202118  3662    7001    7   12  288247  253002.2    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  0   1054464 976361.9    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  1   1047449 1002202 0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  2   1047449 997478.2    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  3   1047449 997478.2    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  4   1047449 998023.2    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  5   1047449 998023.2    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  6   1047449 998023.2    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  7   1047449 998023.2    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  8   1047449 998023.2    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  9   1047449 998023.2    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  10  1047449 985049.8    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  11  1047449 985049.8    0   121
202118  3662    7001    15  12  1047449 985049.8    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  0   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  1   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  2   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  3   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  4   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  5   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  6   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  7   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  8   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  9   40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  10  40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  11  40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    2010    15  12  40000   17209.37    0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  0   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  1   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  2   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  3   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  4   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  5   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  6   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  7   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  8   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  9   0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  10  0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  11  0   680 0   121
202118  3662    3017    15  12  0   680 0   121
```

Hopefully that makes sense , I'm pretty stump on figuering this out without plsql and I was wondering if i can just do it without using PL/SQL?

Comment: Can you simply your sample data

Comment: @Miguel do you want to get *all* the missing rows from last FY for *only* the max FY? or just one row from the last FY? If so, Which one - max FP?

Comment: @Miguel Please add expected output in the question

Comment: @Guv the example output is shown above. It contains the extra values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
;
-- Generate some numbers on the fly
WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT  LEVEL AS n
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20
),
-- Get the year range
fy_range AS (
    SELECT   CAST(MIN(FY) AS INT) AS Min_FY
            ,CAST(MAX(FY) AS INT) AS Max_FY
    FROM G_LEDGER
),
-- Get list of financial periods (could also generate values on the fly here, if desired)
fp_values AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(FP AS INT) AS FP
    FROM G_LEDGER
),
-- Generate list of all FY values, for which we may need to fill-in values
years AS (
    SELECT Min_FY + n AS fy
    FROM numbers
    CROSS APPLY fy_range fyr
    WHERE n <= Max_FY - Min_FY
),
-- Get last values for each FUND, ORG, ACCT combination
last_values AS(
    SELECT   FUND
            ,ORG
            ,ACCT
            ,FY
            ,FP
            ,BUDGET
            ,YTD
            ,ENCB
            ,PROG
    FROM G_LEDGER l
    WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT   FUND
                    ,ORG
                    ,ACCT
                    ,MAX(FY) AS Max_FY
                    ,MAX(FP) AS Max_FP
            FROM G_LEDGER
            WHERE FUND = l.FUND
            AND ORG = l.ORG
            AND ACCT = l.ACCT
            GROUP BY FUND
                    ,ORG
                    ,ACCT
            HAVING MAX(FY) = l.FY
            AND MAX(FP) = l.FP
    )
)
-- Fill-in missing years/periods using last values
SELECT lv.FUND
        ,lv.ORG
        ,lv.ACCT
        ,yr.fy
        ,SUBSTR('0' || CAST(fp.FP AS VARCHAR(10)), -2, 2) AS FP
        ,lv.BUDGET
        ,lv.YTD
        ,lv.ENCB
        ,lv.PROG
FROM last_values lv
INNER JOIN years yr
    ON lv.FY <= yr.fy
INNER JOIN fp_values fp
    ON lv.FY < yr.fy
    OR (lv.FY = yr.fy AND lv.FP < fp.FP)

UNION ALL

-- Add all existing values to the list
SELECT   FUND
        ,ORG
        ,ACCT
        ,FY
        ,FP
        ,BUDGET
        ,YTD
        ,ENCB
        ,PROG
FROM G_LEDGER

-- Sort the list, if desired
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: serge this is almost precisely what I want but for some reason or another, the  acct 3017 repeats fp 01 three times when it gets to FY 08? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get the last FY data brought forward into the latest FY for those Accounts which doesn't have any in the latest FY. You can find the records using window functions and UNION it with the rest like so:

```
SELECT 
  fund, org, acct,
  Max_fy_overall fy,       -- Project the values into latest FY
  , fp ,budget, ytd, encb, prog
FROM
  (SELECT g.*,
     Max(fy) over (partition by acct) max_fy
     Max(fy) over () max_fy_overall
  FROM g_ledger g
  ) t
WHERE 
and max_fy <> max_fy_overall
And fy = max_fy
UNION ALL
select * from g_ledger;  -- And rest of the records.
```

Comment: Gurv this is very close almost exactly what I need. But I have one small dilemma. I need the FY and FP to basically contain fp 1...12 for the accounts which doesn't have the latest FY and FP. If you look at my expected output value repeat 1..12

Comment: @Miguel that's even more easy. See my updated answer.